# Elements unintentionally resize on side refresh

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile application, and on certain pages, such as for example this one: "http://olkensway.se/upplevdinkommun/activities.php?community_id=6&category_id=1", I'm facing a problem. When the page is loaded the first time, it shows correctly, but the problem occurs when I refresh the page (by pressing F5). Try and see for yourselves. The search field re-sizes and becomes much larger than what is supposed to be. This problem occurs both in my desktop browser (Tested with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer) and my mobile browser (Google Chrome as well). Using Google, I haven't found anybody with the same problem yet. I'm new to both jQueryMobile and web design in general. Is this a problem with my PHP, HTML or CSS. Some conflict with jQM? Please tell if I should show more code than what is available by viewing the page's source.

EDIT: It can be worth telling that I have other pages, not using any PHP, where this isn't a problem. So it's likely come conflict there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I load the page, the search thing is taking up the entire page. After inspecting the element in chrome, the article element's font size is 200% (.ui-body-c) . When I unchecked that it went to a "normal" size. I'm not sure exactly what you want it to look like, but maybe that's your problem? hopefully that helps

Comment: Yes, thank you! For some reason, I had added a class in a custom stylesheet earlier. In that class, I changed the font-family and size. Strange thing is that the class didn't apply on page load, but only on refresh. Whatever, now it works and that before Christmas too. Merry Christmas to you!